# Ember 1.13+ precompile templates with maven

Tags: ember.js, maven-plugin

We're migrating one of our projects from Ember 1.4.0 to 1.13.12 (limited by IE8 support) and I'm running into some issues with the template compiler.

We're using maven as a build tool and until now we stuck to rhino to compile the Handlebars templates. It seems we're getting some issues since the templates are compiled as Handlebars.template rather than Ember.TEMPLATE.

Is there any way to handle this with maven/bower or do we need to switch the build tool completely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went for grunt and frontend-maven-plugin. Seems to do the trick for now